# How to change the orientation to resize?

Tags: modeling, objects, transforms, origin

I don't know what I did, but now the resize follows the cursor, When I resize the object goes away. How can I change the orientation to the object again?

[image]

Note: I hid the cursor because I think this could solve this problem, it is at the world origin.

Answer (score 0):

You've selected the 3D cursor as *Transform Pivot Point*, so you need to switch to *Median Point* for example:

[image]